# How to document PHP @return when you are returning view in MVC

Tags: php, yii, return, docblocks

So let's say that in my controller inside some of my methods I want to return a view like this:

```
return $this->render('home', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
```

In my doc block, I want to document what this method is returning. I do not know how to document that this method is returning a view. Is that a resource ? Is it mixed ?

Is this valid? :

```
@return resource
```

And how do you document that your method is returning redirect to some other page ?

Comment: you are returning a string, as I see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docblock is just giving you typehinting in your IDE and making things more readable.  You can absolutely do @return resource, if that's what you're returning, but you can also just include more comments too

```
/**
*  This function returns a view which then redirects the user to another page
*
*  @param string $model The model we looked at
*  @return resource The page to redirect to
*/
function foo($model){
    return $this->render('home', [
    'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

If there's a more specific class in your framework for what the actual return from $this->render is, then you should probably include that, but if you're saying $this->render redirects the page, then there's actually no reason to return it inside this function since those calls won't happen, and it can just be a void function (or you can return a boolean in case things fail)

Comment: I am using yii2 framework, and there you have to return calls to views. So view can be considered to be a resource ? I know that usually you are using resource when your are returning database connections and maybe query calls.

Comment: So if you're talking about: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-viewrenderer.html#render()-detail you can see the return type for render is a string.  Your docblock should just be reflecting the actual class type, or primitive type that you're returning.

Comment: Wow, I never thought to consult the API doc. One more question, the "resource" term is a bit vague to me. Can you please explain where it would be appropriate to use it ?

Comment: No problem, a resource is a special type of variable, you can see the specifics in the php documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php